# The DateTime parameter is not displayed by using the regional setting format of a CRM 2011 in SSRS 2012

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012

We are facing an issue at our project related to date parameters where after changing the date with the date picker it changes the date format. 
We use the Canadian format dd/MM/yyyy but report date picker showing (yyyy-dd-mm).

we use **CRM 2011** in **SSRS 2012**.

There are no custom logic on the parameter at all.

[image]

After clicking the report view button in the report then date picker value has changed to below?

[image]

We have tried below option and still we are experiencing the same issue for all the reports which use date pickers:

- Modifying regional settings on CRM server
- Modifying regional settings on SSRS server
- Modified user regional settings in control panel
- Modified browser language settings
- Changing global date format in CRM organization
- Changing the personal date format in CRM options
- Adding a Language element to the report .rdl
- Modifying the date format by javascript
- Modifying the report viewer control on the CRM and SSRS servers
- Separating Date and Time portions of the date parameter

Comment: Have you tried resetting IIS after changing the regional settings on your CRM server?

Comment: yes we have done IIS RESET as well as server restart.But no luck.

Comment: Did you as well cleared the browser cache on the client?

Comment: Yes, I have cleared the browser cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have installed **RU 18** and still issue was not fixed.

After that we have done Long days of investigation and we were able to fix this issue by below way.

we have opened report viewer page in below folder in CRM server and update culture of the page to **Culture="en-US"**

C:\Program Files\Microsoft CRM\CRMWeb\CRMReports\rsviewer
QuirksReportViewer.aspx page

<%@ Page language="c#" Inherits="Microsoft.Crm.Web.Reporting.RemoteSrsReportViewer" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="true" EnableEventValidation="false" **Culture="en-US"**